# usb audio device numer changes for default device

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, usb, alsa

this is the output of /proc/asound/modules

```
 0 snd_bcm2835
 1 vc4
 2 vc4
 3 snd_usb_audio
```

I want usb as default and put it to /etc/asound.conf

```
defaults.pcm.card 3
defaults.ctl.card 3
```

Problem is that after every reboot the usb device number changes randomly between 1 and 3.

I tried with different numers in /lib/modprobe.d/aliases.conf which had basically no effect.

```
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

What can I do that usb audio becomes tue default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce a certain order of sound drivers, use the `slots` option of the `snd` module:

```
options snd slots=snd-bcm2835,vc4,vc4,snd-usb-audio
```

Independently from that, the `defaults.xxx.cards` settings also accept the card ID (which is found in [brackets] in `/proc/asound/cards`).